# Closure of a point + a set is equal to the point + closure the set in normed spaces

Tags: general-topology, normed-spaces

$Let (X, \lvert \lvert . \rvert \rvert)  $ be a normed space. Then prove for any $ A,B \subset X  $ , $x_0 \in X $,
$$ cl(x_0 + A) =x_0 + cl(A)  $$  where $cl$ denotes closure.

to show  one inclusion ($ \subset  $) side :
take $ y \in  cl(x_0 + A) $ . So, $ \exists $ a sequence $ \{y_n\} \in (x_0 +A) $ s.t  $  \lim (y_n) = y $. But at the same time for each n, $ y_n = x_0 + a_n  $ for $ a_n \in A $.  So, given $\varepsilon >0 , \exists N $ s.t $ \forall n> N \quad ||a_n +x_0 - y || < \varepsilon. $ It means that $\lim a_n = y-x_0 $. This shows that $y-x_0 \in cl(A).$ Hence, $y \in x_0+ cl(A).$

Is someting wrong in flow of my logic since I am not satisfied with my proof. Something I don't know bothers me. Can you help me what can cause a problem in this reasoning? Also , do I need to prove other side as well or is it trivial ?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your proof - this problem is unlikely to provide a particularly illuminating solution since it is just a matter of applying definitions. I would recommend going through the other inclusion to ensure your understanding.

Comment: @Jason thank you so much.

Comment: Use that $f(x)  =x_0 + x$ is a homeomorphism of $X$ so preserves closures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sequences are not needed;  all you need is that $f(x) = x + x_0$ is a homeomorphism in any topological vecor space (all vector operations are continuous, and the inverse is another translation), and for any homeomorphism $f$ we have $\overline{f(A)} = f[\overline{A}]$.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is basically fine, though you make it harder than it needs to be. Also you skip some small details (like an implicit use of the triangle inequality) while being very explicit with others (using $\epsilon$'s), which makes me think you might not know exactly what you're skipping.

Here's a quicker way to jump to the end. Since $y_n = x_0 + a_n$ converges to $y$, $a_n = y_n - x_0$ converges to $y - x_0 \in cl(A)$. Thus $y \in x_0 + cl(A)$.

I would say the other direction is a little easier than that direction, but whether or not it's "trivial" depends on your understanding. If you're not sure, try to do write it out.